# Why Can't Energy Be Created Or Destroyed (Ik this has been asked numerous times by mine is slightly different)

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I've heard a lot of times that energy cannot be created or destroyed. I get this in a nonfundamental way, a car's energy is the form of gas is transferred into another type of energy which allows the car to move, etc. Anyways, if energy cannot be created or destroyed, how does our universe exist? Our universe is made of energy so if energy can't be created then why do we have it? Also on a side note, if time has no beginning or end then how does time exist? If something has no beginning then from my understanding, why should it have an end? It sounds to me like time can't exist since something must be created by something else.

Comment: Why would the universe not exist if energy is conserved? Why would time not exist if the universe “had no beginning or end”?

Comment: This post is getting downvoted, probably because the phrasing could be improved and it needs to be a little more focused. But it’s not a bad question. If you downvote please provide some feedback to the user first.

Comment: I just added more to my question and hopefully, it makes more sense now.

Comment: *something must be created by something else* -- citation needed.

Answer (score 3):

Energy is not a physical substance, but a mathematical object - an integral of motion of the equations describing the world, whose existence follows from the basic symmetries of the Universe. Thus, the energy is conserved by definition.

Comment: Even if energy is a mathematical object, it tries to describe a physical thing, the world. Also, this still doesn't answer my question at a fundamental level, if energy follows the base symmetries of the universe then where are those symmetries of the universe from? I feel like this is a sort of paradox but since I'm no scientist on the matter, you can dispute me on this.

Comment: I think the nature of energy and the origins of the universe are two different questions. Perhaps you need to clarify your question. It could be also helpful to do some background research and give some references - so that people could help you more meaningfully.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've read the newest edit of my comment, but if the nature of energy and the nature of the universe are entwined is it really that different of a question? (I'll look into this more)

Comment: Your link between the energy an the existence of the universe is unclear, and I tried to address this in my answer: the universe is not made of energy, it is not a physical substance. It is one of the integrals of motion, alongside the momentum and the angular momentum.

Answer (score 1):

Conservation of energy , conservation of momentum and conservation of angular momentum, are three laws developed from observation of  innumerable experiments . These observations have been fitted with mathematical models that have them inherent in their formulation and thus in all solutions.

Now the question

> if energy cannot be created or destroyed, how does our universe exist?

is answered by astrophysical cosmological models, that attempt to mathematically fit observations of our universe. The current dominant model is the [Big Bang model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), where the energy existing in our universe was created at the beginning of the universe's time once,  and this is the energy we have at present. [General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) theory, on which the model depends, allows for energy to be created and destroyed at the beginning of time and only as time advances, the law of conservation prevails.